# Difficulty with Django Migrations

Tags: django, postgresql

What are some good best practices to prevent the following. 
Often, during django development I use postgres. If I roll back to an earlier commit, often new migrations will break things irreparably, because the postgres context is unknown to the older code. I have tried the syncdb etc, I have tried makemigrations on single apps, but neither seem to fix the problem. 
Also, if creating a new postgres db and deleting all the migrations and pycache folders, this too often causes problems that are not straightforward to fix. 
Is the answer to simply use sqlite during development, has anyone else encountered this?
Details: django 2.0.5 postgres: most current.

Comment: you can revert migrations to last working stage,

`python manage.py migrate <app_name> <last_stable_migration_name_to which_you_want_to_revert>`

Comment: Thank you! So, this deletes the tables that may be problematic? The migration name I assume comes from the given apps migrations file. Yes?

Comment: yes, it unapply all the migrations done after the migration file you choose to revert.